# Delete current database in MongoDB using Jessenger / Lumen

Tags: mongodb, lumen

I am using **Jessenger** in Lumen for handling MongoDB.
I have a scenario where I need to delete/drop the current database.
For example, in mongo db, I am executing the following queries.

```
use '367';
db.dropDatabase();
```

Where 367 is a database. I want to drop this database dynamically in lumen API using jessenger.
I am unable to find any help so far.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`db.dropDatabase();`  is just a shell helper. It calls "dropDatabase" command on the wire. In PHP it must be something like this:

```
$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://.....");
$manager->executeCommand("367",  new MongoDB\Driver\Command(["dropDatabase" => 1]));
```